Sabre dev api integration
I am trying to integrate with Sabre's api using PHP and my test credentials. However, I get this response 'Array ( [error] => invalid_client [error_description] => Wrong clientID or clientSecret )'.
Sabre documentation:
https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/session_management/token_create_api/v2
https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency/developer-guides/rest-apis-token-credentials
Any suggestions or help with my code is appreciated.
$saberUrl = 'https://api.platform.sabre.com/v2/auth/token';
$credentials = [
    'user_id' => 'V1:uname:DEVCENTER:AA',
    'password' => 'pwd'
];

$base64EncodeConcat =base64_encode(base64_encode($credentials['user_id']) . ':' . base64_encode($credentials['password']));

// Initialize cURL session
$curl = curl_init($saberUrl);

// Set cURL options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization: Basic ' . $base64EncodeConcat
));

// Include the grant_type parameter in the POST fields
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

// Execute cURL session
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Close cURL session
curl_close($curl);

// Process the response
$data = json_decode($response, true);

// Output the data
print_r($data);


The user_id must be in the format 'user_id' => 'V1:uname:DEVCENTER:EXT' as it looks like a DEV Studio generated credential.
